Where to store the user progress?
I'm developing the application in NextJS with MongoDB. This app features a list of tasks with checkboxes and buttons. If the user selects the correct combination of checkboxes, they receive a score of 1.
The question is: Where should I store the score?
One option that comes to mind is to use local storage for a quick response and to avoid a lot of requests to the DB.
The second one: when the user completes a task and earns a score, send a request to API endpoint to store the score directly in the database.

What do you do with the score which you get from the user? Like do you process it in the backend?

@Anay not yet, but I will process it later.

If you've to process it later, Then Database only, Otherwise you'll not be able to access it.

for me the best way is to store it using redux that will allow you to keep the response as fast as possible during the session
while updating the slice content in the redux after user leave the update or edit list upload it to the db
and any time user re visit the website fetch the data and store it in the redux slice

Can you please reformat your answer and add punctuation to make it readable?

As you are giving points for selecting the correct combination of checkboxes, You should save the response in the database. It will save the response even if the user reloads the page.
